# In jquery validation for textbox value 0 or greater than 0 based on dropdown value

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

Here I'm using jquery validate plugin. In my form are having one drop down select and one input text box. When I select drop down value 0 then text box should be accept greater than 0 or else have to through error. If I select dropdown value 1 or 2  then text box should be accept only 0, not more than 0, have to through error. This is my requirement. Please help on this.

reference: http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/vqnpy/11/

Comment: so what did you try? I could find any js script in that jsfiddle you have shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add a custom validation rule for text box . which checks the check box value and the drop down value.

in your form validation

```
textbox: {
      required: true,
      custom_rule : true
       }
```

then

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_rule", function(value, element) {

var dropdown_val = $("#dropdown").val();

if((dropdown_val==0 && value>0) || (dropdown_val==1 || dropdown_val==2 ) && value==0))
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}


}, "if drop down 0 , input should greater than 0 , else input should be 0");
```

Comment: This code is almost fine for me. The thing is I need to display those error messages based on the value. Can you help me? Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else was dropped onto this post. kanishka's post solved my problem too, but I too needed a custom message depending on the value. So what needs to be done is the following:

in the form validation:

```
rules: {
    textbox: {
      required: true,
      custom_rule : true
       }
}, messages {
    textbox: {
       required: mymessageprocessor //this is a function that returns custom messages
    }
```

then add this javascript at the end:

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_rule", function(value, element) {

var dropdown_val = $("#dropdown").val();

if((dropdown_val==0 && value>0) || (dropdown_val==1 || dropdown_val==2 ) && value==0))
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}


}, "");

function mymessageprocessor() {
    var dropdown_val = $("#dropdown").val();
    if (dropdown_val == 0) {
        return "value is zero";
    } else {
        return "value is greater than zero";
    }
```